# How to debug the loop in mips if its giving exception

Tags: assembly, mips

I am fairly new to Mips, and I have been given an assignment where I need to print the following pattern but It is giving me an Exception. I have tried debugging and I know that problem is in the loop but it's not working out. Please help!

**5
54
543
5432
54321**

That's what I have done so far:

main:

```
    li $t0 , 5  #rows
    move $t1,$t0 #i
    move $t2,$t0 #j
    addi $t3,$t3 , 1
```

outerLoop:

```
    beq $t3 , $t1 , end
    sub $t1 , $t1 , $t3
```

innerLoop:

```
    bgt $t1 , $t2 , newline1    
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t2               
    syscall
    sub $t2 , $t2 , $t3 
    j innerLoop
```

newline1:

```
     li $v0, 4
     la $a0, newline            
     syscall
     j outerLoop
```

end:

```
 li $v0, 10
     syscall
```

Comment: You forgot to include the full, exact error message(s) in your question, and to point out which line(s) of code the error(s) refer to.

Comment: You've also only shown us a fragment of your code, which makes it impossible for anyone else to reproduce the issue or to know what the values of the various registers are when this code begins executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I have figured out what you are asking and the problem in your code is(let me know if i am wrong) but what i have figured out is that every time it goes to inner loop it decrements J, but basically when you go back to outer loop you need J to be equal to rows and one more problem in your code is that 'i' would decrement once your inner loop has terminated.

Try This Code, I have added comments for better understanding.

outerLoop:

```
beq $t3 , $t1 , end #1<i
move $t2, $t0  # j = rows, everytime you go to innerloop from outerloop
```

innerLoop:

```
bgt $t1 , $t2 , newline1    #if j<i then exit the inner loop and print newline
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t2               #Print vaue of j
syscall
sub $t2 , $t2 , $t3     #j--
j innerLoop     #loop until j<i
```

newline1:

```
 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, newline            #print newLine
 syscall
 sub $t1 , $t1 , $t3        #Increment i and jump back to first Loop
 j outerLoop
```